# Clear Notification Queue for a Gtk.Switch

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygobject

Lately I've been around here asking some questions relative to this (Go to my profile to see my last 2 questions)

My objective was to make a Gtk.Switch that "auto-deactivates" itself if it detects an exeption while user tries to activate it.

My last two attempts where unsuccessful, resulting into an infinite loop while trying to code the "auto-deactivation" func.

After some research, I found something interesting about Notifications.

It appears that, Gtk "Stores" notifications from objects into a queue when you "freeze" them with `object.freeze_notify()`

Now that I know that Gtk stores notification events into a temporal queue, it would be nice to "clear" that queuue so I can avoid that infinite loop that results from trying to deactivate a switch from inside the event handler.

### Now, my question here is: Is there any possible way to "Clear" a Gtk.object's notification queue?

EDIT:

I want to do this:

- User runs program --> Tries to activate Switch --> Program detects exeption --> Don't close entire program, just deactivate switch again as if user hadn't touched it

I want this to work in both states (ON & OFF)

If user wants to turn switch OFF (It was ON), and program detects an exeption, turn switch ON automatically again, like if nothing happend & vice versa

I'm using Python2.7, Glade to design GUI, Gtk 3.4 and Ubuntu 14.04.5 as my OS

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import subprocess
import sys
import subprocess
import signal
import time
from subprocess import call
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

builder = Gtk.Builder()
#builder.add_from_file("""./Testing2.glade""")
builder.add_from_string("""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.2"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="halign">baseline</property>
    <property name="valign">baseline</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Test</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <property name="icon_name">applications-accessories</property>
    <property name="urgency_hint">True</property>
    <property name="has_resize_grip">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="halign">center</property>
        <property name="valign">center</property>
        <property name="margin_left">24</property>
        <property name="margin_right">24</property>
        <property name="margin_top">24</property>
        <property name="margin_bottom">24</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">16</property>
        <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="primary_icon_name">applications-games</property>
            <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">Texto</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSwitch" id="switch1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>


""")

window1 = builder.get_object('window1')
textie = builder.get_object('entry1')
switchie =  builder.get_object('switch1')

def TurnOn(switch, active):

    print switchie.get_active()

    if yay == "":
        switchie.set_active(not switchie.get_active())

def TurnOff(switch, active):

    print switchie.get_active()

    if yay == "":
        switchie.set_active(not switchie.get_active())

def ParentTrue(switch,active):
    yay = textie.get_text().rstrip()
    if yay == "":
        def Hi():
            print switchie.get_active()
            switchie.handler_block(connecting)
            switchie.set_active(False)
            switchie.handler_unblock(connecting)
            return True
        Hi()

def ParentFalse(switch,active):
    yay = textie.get_text().rstrip()
    if yay == "":
        def Hi():
            print switchie.get_active()
            switchie.handler_block(connecting)
            switchie.set_active(True)
            switchie.handler_unblock(connecting)
            return True
        Hi()

switchie.set_active(True)

def qck():
    while True:
        os.environ["SomeVar"] = str(switchie.get_active())


p1 = threading.Thread(target=qck)

p1.start()

if not os.environ["SomeVar"]:
    connecting = switchie.connect('notify::active', ParentFalse)
if os.environ["SomeVar"]:
    connecting = switchie.connect('notify::active', ParentTrue)


window1.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
window1.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window1.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    Gtk.main()
```

This code just works from OFF to ON. It won't work when you change from ON to OFF

Example:

If I execute this code, and try to activate switch WITHOUT entering text first, It won't change, BUT if you enter text (It doesn't matter, just enter a single letter if you want) it will allow you to move the switch from OFF to ON. Unfortunately It won't do anything special if you want to move switch from ON to OFF even if you try to do so without entering text first

There are some stub funcs and vars in the code. It's just some test code, so it really doesn't matter how clean is it, I'll take care of it when trying to include this code in the final program

Comment: This sounds like a design problem on your side. notifys are inherently tied to the property values: if the property value has changed then there should be a notify after thawing -- conceptually it's not "queuing the notifys" but checking if the property value has changed since freeze. If you don't want to receive the notify then either make sure the property value is at the original value at thaw time or disconnect the signal handler before thawing. 
If you want an actual answer you probably need to add a code example that shows the problem.

Comment: A third option is to block a specific connection, which requires saving the return from `g_signal_connect()`. Show your code anyway, so we can figure out if there's a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: I'll update my question with code then